# Editing Boot Menu options Mac (Bootcamp)

Tags: backup, bootcamp, partition

I had a problem where I was wanting to make my windows partition bigger using Winclone. I also used a file-based backup in Windows. I made the wrong, move and after restoring the Winclone image, I then restored the file based backup on the wrong partition. Luckily I had a backup of my Mac from a few hours before, so it was nearly a train smash. I've restored my Winclone image to a new (bigger) partition.Just wondering how to get rid of the 'recovery-10.xx.x' drive from the boot menu after pressing option key? Bootcamp and MacOS still show up fine by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly (no guarantee of that ;-) the Recovery partition usually shows up in the "Option boot menu."

If I am inexplicably wrong likely the only way to get rid of it would be to boot from an OS install thumb drive that you created previously (you **did** create one previously, didn't you?) and reinstall from scratch. during the OS install open Disk Utility, delete both partitions and then create one new one to install Mac OS onto and install. The install process will re-create the emergency boot partition behind the scenes. Once that is done you can restore your files and apps from your back up that you cleverly thought to make before wiping your hard drive.

There I think I have covered most of the bases here... I hope.

Comment: It's normal for the recovery partition to appear *unless* the macOS startup volume is being managed by Core Storage. Actually, I'd argue that it really should appear even then, but for technical reasons it can't. Anyway, it's normal and does not indicate any problem at all.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! Yeah it didn't show up with my initial bootcamp partition.